# Azure Text Analytics docker image: dotnet_client exit status 134 on M1/M2 Mac

Tags: .net, azure, docker, azure-cognitive-services

I'm following the instructions from Azure Cognitive Text Analytics on running their Healthcare docker image locally. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/text-analytics-for-health/how-to/use-containers?tabs=language

Running the following on an M2 Macbook ends with the `dotnet_client` continously exiting with status code 134.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:5000 --cpus 4 --memory 12g \
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/textanalytics/healthcare:latest \
Eula=accept \
Billing=${LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT} \
ApiKey=${LANGUAGE_KEY}
```

I've tried running the image with x86 (using both `--platform linux/amd64` and by setting `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`

This is the repeated logging from the image:

```
2023-07-31 08:16:37,893 INFO spawned: 'dotnet_client' with pid 579
2023-07-31 08:16:38,897 INFO success: dotnet_client entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-07-31 08:16:44,124 WARN exited: dotnet_client (exit status 134; not expected)
```